# Shortcut - El Capitan Dialog Box switch between option

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

How do we switch between options in confirm dialog boxes on El Capitan.
Older OSXs was switching by using spacebar. Not working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** then select **Keyboard**.

In the **Shortcuts** tab you will find an option for "Full Keyboard Access". Set the radio button for **All Controls**.

When confronted with a dialog box with buttons, <kbd>Tab</kbd> will now work to change focus between the buttons.  This setting can be turned off by key combination of <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> function key too if needed.)

---

[image]