# Keyboard Shortcut :: Remove Google Chrome Bookmark

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

I keep accidentally typing <kbd>Command + D</kbd> in Google Chrome, because I'm used to that taking me to the Address Bar on Windows systems. This results in a bookmark being created.

My question is: How do I use the keyboard to reverse this action, to remove the bookmark that was created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edit

To reverse and accidental bookmark, go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** and turn on **Full Keyboard Access** for "All controls". Now one can use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to highlight the *Remove* button then hit <kbd>return</kbd> to reverse.

---

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to highlight the URL thus taking you to the Address bar.

From [Chrome Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en):
⌘+L Highlights the URL.

Takes a bit of retraining of muscle memory, but this is faster and is less complicated than trying to remap the Bookmark shortcut, which is built in by Google.

NOTE: This works in Safari and several other browsers too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you didn't answer my question. I'm aware of the CMD + L shortcut to get to the address bar, but I sometimes type resort to CMD + D. My question is: once I've screwed up by pressing CMD + D, how do I undo it, using the keyboard?

Comment: Oh, you mean undo the save bookmark?  It appeared to me from your question that you wanted to change the ⌘+D behavior.  Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Nope, I don't want to change the behavior. I want to reverse the accidental operation that I performed. What's the shortcut to hit "Remove" when the "bookmark added" box pops up?

Comment: If you have [Full keyboard assess set on in your System prefs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211739/120171), you can tab to the button and hit enter.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood at first, glad it worked for you! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

"My question is: once I've screwed up by pressing CMD + D, how do I undo it, using the keyboard?"

Answer: press option + R on mac keyboard

Comment: That is not given in googles documentation https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Caddress-bar-shortcuts%2Cwebpage-shortcuts%2Cgoogle-chrome-feature-shortcuts%2Ctab-and-window-shortcuts where did you get that from?

Comment: On the internet and it works on Mac?

Comment: awesome, it works 

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the bookmark, I press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> again which brings the popup toolbox having <kbd>Remove</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a bookmark can be done as:
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>

If you have Better Touch Tool, it is extremely easy to configure this sequence. See the below screenshot. I just configured <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and it works wonders:

[image]